# How to prevent function rerendering inside render() loop

Tags: reactjs

I have code that contains `.map()` inside `render()` that renders many `img`-es. Image itself has props `src` with image information- which is taken from function. To take this information I am using `this.getImage(barcode)` inside `.map.`, and unfortunately, it always rerenders. Without "barcode" image can-not be drawn.

I created new component inside `.map()` with function and image, but result was same.
Bthw, I think it will be more clear with code:

inside render():

```
        {details.map((detail, idx) => (
                    <tr key={idx}>
                      <td>{detail.code}</td>
                      <td>
                        {selectedPrintType.value === "2" && (
                          <Fragment>
                            {this.getBarcode(detail.code)}
                              <div>
                                <img
                                  src={imgSrc}
                                  id="myimg"
                                  alt=""
                                  style={{
                                    padding: "10px",
                                    width: OS === "Linux" ? "270px" : "auto",
                                  }}
                                />
                              </div>
                          </Fragment>
                        )}
                      </td>
        ))}
```

function getBarcode():

```
    getBarcode = barcode => {
    let { imgSrc } = this.state;
    let OS = "Win";
    Axios.get("/api/barcode", { params: { barcode, OS } })
      .then(res => res.data)
      .then(png => {
        imgSrc = "data:image/png;base64," + png.toString("base64");
        this.setState({ imgSrc });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
```

Expected output is only one render per barcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `render` method should be "pure" and not have side effects. Currently, every render is calling `getBarcode`, which kicks of a request, which updates the component state, which triggers a re-render. Can you move the `getBarcode` call to `componentDidMount` so it's only called once on mount?

> The render() function should be pure, meaning that it does not modify component state, it returns the same result each time it’s invoked, and it does not directly interact with the browser.

[React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render)

Comment: Thank you, for good suggestion, but I think  that I will not be able to move `getBarcode()` into `componentDidMount` because I have to pass `(detail.barcode)` into `getBarcode()` like - `getBarcode(detail.barcode)`, which is inside render.

Comment: What is `details` and where does it come from?

Comment: It comes from other function.                                                                           
 Inside render(): `onClick={() => this.invoiceDetails(invoice)}>`
Outside render: 
  ```javascript 
invoiceDetails = invoice => {
    Axios.get("/api/report/history/invoice/details", {
      params: {
        invoicenumber: invoice.invoicenumber,
      },
    })
      .then(res => res.data)
      .then(details => {
        this.setState({ details, markedInvoice: invoice });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };```

Comment: Got it, so where you're calling `this.setState({ details, markedInvoice: invoice });` can you also iterate through details and call `getBarcode` here and save that to state as well? You need to avoid having side effects in render (making requests)

Comment: Also, I have one more `.map()` which finds `(invoice)` as a parameter and puts it into `invoiceDetails`. `invoice` comes from other function `searchInvoices`, which is also with parameters. Whole picture is -  three cascading functions, each with parameters from parent.

Comment: thank you, your last suggestion works perfectly. Here is my changed `invoiceDetails`:
```invoiceDetails = invoice => {
    Axios.get("/api/report/history/invoice/details", {
      params: {
        invoicenumber: invoice.invoicenumber,
      },
    })
      .then(res => res.data)
      .then(details => {
        details.map((detail, idx) => this.getBarcode(detail.code));
        this.setState({ details, markedInvoice: invoice });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the setState from render function anyway. To achieve that please follow the step
Create a new function and call in componentDidMount

```
componentDidMount() {
    //....other stuffs
    this.getOutput();
}
```

Define the function

```
getOutput = () => {
  let output = [];

  output.push(
    details.map((detail, idx) => (
      return 
      (<tr key={idx}>
        <td>{detail.code}</td>
        <td>
          {selectedPrintType.value === "2" && (
            <Fragment>
              {this.getBarcode(detail.code)}
                <div>
                  <img
                    src={imgSrc}
                    id="myimg"
                    alt=""
                    style={{
                      padding: "10px",
                      width: OS === "Linux" ? "270px" : "auto",
                    }}
                  />
                </div>
            </Fragment>
          )}
        </td>
      </tr>
      )
    ))
  )

  this.setState({
    outputData: output
  })
}
```

and inside render just use

```
 render() {
     <div>
       //....other stuffs
       {this.state.outputData}

     </div>
   }
```

and leave the `getBarcode()` as same.

Hope this will work.

Comment: Thank you @Sanchit Srivastava for reply. Problem of this solution is that I can't get `details` information to map. To get them, `.map()` has to be within `render()` function, because details information comes from another function, which comes from third function. All functions contains "cascading" parameters - root function gives parameters to child and so on. May be I missing something in your reply, but I already found solution which was written in comment section to first reply.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you're setting state once you get the image src i.e. this.setState({ imgSrc });

So can't you make use of shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){} to identify whether your component render lifecycle should continue?